Is it possible to convert LabVIEW VI's into human-readable text/code?
I was curious if there is a tool or any way to convert a LabVIEW VI into a human-readable form.
My intentions for reading LabVIEW code in a different way then in Block-Diagram is e.g. making a diff over multiple files and looking for "obvious" differences. I know that there is a tool for this purpose (LV-Compare) but that again is only possible with LabVIEW itself.
VI's by itself are only in binary and even opening a VI and immediately saving it can (or will) change the binary file (even with the same code).
I already looked in the internet and in the official NI forum but couldn't find an answer.

If your goal is to make a diff tools for LabVIEW this one exist: https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA03q000000YHwACAW&l=en-CH
However only available on all edition since LV 2022 Q3...
If you want to inspect the VIs in more deep you can have a look at the Heap Peek: https://labviewwiki.org/wiki/Heap_Peek
As far as I know, it's not possible to convert LabVIEW to human readable, especially since LabVIEW is written in G which translates badly to text...
Thomas, Certified LabVIEW Architect
